# a way to make --no-ff the default behavior of git merge

Tags: git, merge

I want to know if exist some way to make:

> git merge --no-ff mybranche

default behavior for git merge?

The `--no-ff` flag causes the merge to always create a new commit object, even if the merge could be performed with a fast-forward. This avoids losing information about the historical existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that together added the feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `merge.ff` to `false`:

```
git config merge.ff false
```

Add `--global` to set it globally:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

Comment: Relevant documentation can be found at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html.

Comment: Be aware that `git pull` is doing a merge, and therefore will create an explicit commit with this option. You probably want to use `git pull --rebase` instead.